# Selenium - set_window_size() always returning same sized window irrelevant of dimensions specified

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver-python

I am trying to set window size for Firefox Selenium via Python. However, the window is always being resized to the same size, irrelevant of the dimensions passed as parameters to the `set_window_size()` function.

Below is the code I am using:

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")
time.sleep(5)
driver.set_window_size(480,360)
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.get_window_size())
```

The outputted print statement always shows `{width: 1161, height: 661}`

I have updated the geckodriver to the latest version and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 to run the code via an anaconda environment.

I also tried using the `execute_script()` function to set the window size via JS but I got the same result.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Is there any screenshot that you can provide? Also, did you try setting driver.set_window_position(0, 0), then the windows size?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added driver.set_window_position(0,0) and everything is working fine now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set

```
driver.set_window_position(0,0)
```

before setting

```
driver.set_window_size(x, y)
```

Or try setting

```
driver.set_window_size(x, y, windowHandle='current')
```

- Refer: [WebDriver API](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)